# Locally saved credentials google drive api 3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm creating a desktop app in C#. The first time i started my app everything went fine they asked me to log-in and the permission. Now i can't log-in with another account since they saved everything locally.I tried deleting the file at ~/.credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json and yes it worked but again only once they resaved the credentials but somewhere else and i can't find where. I want to be able to log-in from different account and since i also need to change the scope for permission issue i have to delete the previously saved credentials. There is how i log-in.

```
using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(credential.ToString());
        service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });
```

How can i delete the saved credentials ?
How can i disable the credentials saving mechanism ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack. It is very hard for people to help you if you don't post the code you are having a problem with.   It leads to guesses like the following comment.  SO please post code next time

Comment: I am going to guess you are using the Google .net client library, then I am going to guess you are calling  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync .  And tell you that if you change the user parameter in that method it will pop up and request access of a different user.   Credentials are stored based upon that user.

Answer (score 0):

You can "Log out" by calling await `credential.RevokeTokenAsync()` or use another userID in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecretsStream = stream,
        Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly },
        DataStore = new FileDataStore(credPath, true)
    });

    credential = new UserCredential(flow, userId,
        await flow.LoadTokenAsync(userId, CancellationToken.None)
    );

    bool res = await credential.RevokeTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    //credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
    //    .AuthorizeAsync(
    //        stream,
    //        new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly },
    //        userId,
    //        CancellationToken.None,
    //        new FileDataStore("oauth/drive"))
    //    ;
    //Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved");
}
```

To check if credential is existed in local

```
await new FileDataStore(credPath, true).GetAsync<TokenResponse>(userId) != null
//or
await flow.LoadTokenAsync(userId, CancellationToken.None) != null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the token file which in "credPath" folder